# TensorFlow reduce_max for different dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

It is possible to do a tf.reduce_max operation (which is in essence an 'Add:operation') between differents shapes?

I'm getting this error:

```
Tensor("reduce_max/parallel_0/split:0", shape=(900000,),
dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:1) --
Tensor("reduce_max/parallel_1/split:0", shape=(870000,),
dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
Dimensions must be equal, but are 900000 and 870000 for
'reduce_max/Add' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [900000], [870000].
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Always share reproducible code along with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where I have created a ragged tensor(used to create a tensor of variable dimension) then applied reduce_max operation on that.

**Example:**

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a Ragged Tensor of variable length
rt = tf.ragged.constant([[9, 8, 7], [], [6, 5], [4]])
print("Ragged Tensor:","\n",rt,"\n")

# Convert to Tensor to have same length
rt = rt.to_tensor()
print("Tensor of same length:","\n",rt,"\n")

# Apply reduce_max to get the max value along axis=1
rt = tf.reduce_max(rt, axis=1)
print("Reduce Max Tensor:","\n",rt,"\n")
```

**Output -**

```
Ragged Tensor: 
 <tf.RaggedTensor [[9, 8, 7], [], [6, 5], [4]]> 

Tensor of same length: 
 tf.Tensor(
[[9 8 7]
 [0 0 0]
 [6 5 0]
 [4 0 0]], shape=(4, 3), dtype=int32) 

Reduce Max Tensor: 
 tf.Tensor([9 0 6 4], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```